# How do you call wooden extension above water found alongside rivers/ piers

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Where's the difference between 'dock', 'pier' and only one wooden structure? or is this referred to as 'pier'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A pier isn't *alongside* a river: it is usually built on stilts and [projects out to sea](https://images.photowall.com/products/62183/pier-in-horizon.jpg?h=699&q=85).

Comment: "Here, Extension!  Come here, boy!"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a photo or drawing of the thing you're trying to name.

Answer (score 2):

A **pier** *may* be built of wood, but many are constructed of steel pillars. The term does certainly, however, overlap with 'jetty'. It is usually pretty substantial.

The **jetty** is typically long, often wooden, and raised above the water level. Though mooring may be involved, 'A jetty may serve as a breakwater, as a walkway, or both; or, in pairs, as a means of constricting a channel.' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty)]

An example [[Environmental Agency UK](https://environment.data.gov.uk/asset-management/drl-app/revision/22/categories/Structure/asset-types/Jetty)]:

[image]

A **dock** is often ... arguably typically ... far more extensive and complex, right up to massive installations, harbours (thus the Royal Albert Dock in Liverpool). It is always connected with the landing / mooring / unloading of boats (piers may be pleasure installations). Here is a relatively simple example [[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/architecture/comments/1641fgy/how_were_docks_built_in_ancient_times/)]:

[image: Blockquote]

> A **wharf** (pl. wharves or wharfs), **quay**, or **staith/staithe**
> is [again polysemous, basically] a structure on the shore of a harbour or on the bank of a river or
> canal where [boats or] ships may dock to load and unload cargo or passengers.
> Such a structure includes one or more berths (mooring locations) ... [and
> may also be far more substantial,] including piers, warehouses, or other facilities necessary for
> handling the ships. [[Wikipedia; augmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wharf)]

**Fishing platforms** are more often nearer square in proportions [[Kedel Plastics](https://www.kedel.co.uk/sport/recycled-plastic-fishing-peg.html)]:
[image]

Comment: A dock doesn't have to be complex. My home is alongside a small lake, and there's a simple dock that's not much more than a platform (like your fishing platform) with railings along the sides and a gate at the back.

Comment: Many jetties are substantial stone or concrete structures often constructed to protect a harbour or moorings from waves. It creates an area of relatively calm water.

Answer (score -1):

A **plank** is a wooden structure, usually straigbt and often very narrow, upon which one walks on and off from the same end. It's a one-sided path, of sorts.

A **boardwalk** is a wooden structure, sometimes meandering with twists and turns, on which on from one end; and walks off from the other end. It is a two-sided path, of sorts.